# Is open layer 3 is having OL.Control.CacheWrite like open layer 2,And if it is not available now by when we expect to available in open layer 3

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I have code of cache write and read using open layer 2 , Now I am upgrading our open layer 3 . Please help

Answer (score 1):

OpenLayers 3 uses a different approach. You can configure a custom `tileLoadFunction` for tile layers: Instead of setting the `src` on an `Image` directly, you can look up the url in your preferred storage (LocalStorage, IndexDB, ...), and fetch it if available or store it if you want to.

Something like this:

```
new ol.source.TileImage({
  tileLoadFunction: function(tile, src) {
    // try to fetch from local storage
    var dataURI = localStorage.getItem(src);
    if (dataURI) {
      // use cached version
      tile.getImage().src = dataURI;
    } else {
      // load image data
      var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
      client.open('GET', src);
      client.onload(function() {
        var data = 'data:image/png;base64,' +
            btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(this.responseText));
        // use the image data we just loaded
        tile.getImage().src = data;
        // save image data to the cache for later reuse
        localStorage.setItem(src, data);
      });
      client.send();
    }
  }
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Actually we are building a hybrid app and working on adding offline tile loading functionality. How we can access local tiles in in mobile device. We are planning to load local tiles from SD card.Open layer SRc needs the serve address .

Comment: You use `getItem` and `setItem` on `localStorage`. How you access tiles on SD card is a different story and depends on the platform and OS.